# is this potential flow governed by laplacian function unique?

Tags: differential-operators

[image]

I used a finite element method to solve this problem and find no convergence. 
So i wonder whether this equation has no unique solution. 
[image]

Comment: Is "Constant" given, or free? If it's 1 there is $\phi=x$ (or $-x$ depending on $n$ outward or inward)

Comment: no, it is free(i don't know the exact value of this constant). Actually i am investigating the potential flow problem. this problem is the same as in potential flow with three sides assigned the flow velocity and the remaining one side assigned the constant pressure.

Comment: How did you incorporate the constant pressure boundary condition into FEM?